# WCF: How add me custom ServiceBehavior into WCF configuration

Tags: wcf, app-config

Hi I have my own ServiceBehavior:

```
public class StructureMapServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase cdb in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                ChannelDispatcher cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (cd != null)
                {
                    foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
                    {
                        ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider =
                            new StructureMapInstanceProvider(serviceDescription.ServiceType);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }

    }
```

How i can add it in App.config with WCF configuration tool ?

:
[image: WCF configuration tool]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that inherit from `BehaviorExtensionElement`:

```
public class StructureMapServiceBehaviorElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(StructureMapServiceBehavior ); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new StructureMapServiceBehavior ();
    }
}
```

Then register your extension in the config file:

```
<behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="timeService" type="YourAssembly.StructureMapServiceBehaviorElement ,
YourAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</behaviorExtensions>
```

When that is done you can use your extension like any other.

EDIT: To do it using the configuration tool, it is similar. Once the class above is created, register your behavior in the extensions section of the WCF configuration tool (advanced->extensions->behavior element extensions)

Comment: @johann-blais can be StructureMapServiceBehaviorElement  in same project like me wcf libary ? WCF configuration tool, show error: Can locate assembly

Comment: Yes it is possible. Where does this message come from? The configuration tool? Runtime exception?

Comment: @johann-blais exactly in WCF configuration tool. Build fine, and if I open WCF CT, then a got error: (MyAssembly) could not be found. Do you want relocate it ?

Comment: It is probably because the tool running directory is not bin/debug, it cannot find the assembly. Try adding the extension through the tool instead of manually, then it should be able to find it afterwards.

Comment: @johann-blais on behavior in app.config i have this error: Warning The element 'behavior' has invalid child element 'StructureMapBehavior'. List of possible elements expected: 'serviceAuthenticationManager, clear, serviceAuthorization, serviceCredentials, serviceMetadata, serviceSecurityAudit, serviceThrottling, dataContractSerializer, serviceDebug, serviceTimeouts, remove, useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress, persistenceProvider,

Comment: @johann-blais workflowRuntime, etwTracking, bufferedReceive, workflowIdle, workflowUnhandledException, sendMessageChannelCache, sqlWorkflowInstanceStore, workflowInstanceManagement, serviceDiscovery, routing'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom class derived from `BehaviorExtensionElement` which will be responsible for creating your custom behavior. [Here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704148/wsdl-first-approach-how-to-specify-different-names-for-wsdlport-and-wsdlbindin/4705351#4705351) with steps needed to add such behavior in configuration file (extension must be registered first in `behaviorsExtensions` section).

In configuration tool I guess you will first have to register the extension in Advanced > Extensions and after that you will probably will be able to use that service behavior.