# How use function SetEndpointAddress?

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

What should come in the place of ??? (first parameter)

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));    
serviceHost.SetEndpointAddress(???, "http://cvxcvxcvcx");
```

I have specified Endpoint in config file, what should I do to recall him? Can I recall him in this function?

Comment: What I should write in the first parameter?

Comment: I have specified Endpoint in config file, what should I do to recall him?

Answer (score 1):

[It is taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostbase.setendpointaddress.aspx#Y0)

> ServiceHostBase.SetEndpointAddress Method Sets the endpoint address of
>   the specified endpoint to the specified address.
>
> ```
> public void SetEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, string relativeAddress)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> endpoint
>     Type: System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint
>     The service endpoint.
>
> relativeAddress
>     Type: System.String
>     The endpoint address.

For better understanding you should read it [WSDL-first approach: How to specify different names for wsdl:port and wsdl:binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704148/wsdl-first-approach-how-to-specify-different-names-for-wsdlport-and-wsdlbindi)

Comment: The signature of the SetEndpointAddress method looks slightly different at MSDN: [public void SetEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, string relativeAddress)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostbase.setendpointaddress.aspx)

Comment: @dtb: Thanks for improvement. I have changed it.